# revert changes back in my case

Tags: git, github

I was working on `master` branch.

I have made many changes on my project, then **commit** & **pushed** all the changes to remote repository by:

```
git push origin master
```

Then, I made a new branch, and push the latest code to the new branch (to make it a remote branch) like following:

```
git branch new-branch
git checkout new-branch
git push origin new-branch
```

I am now on `new-branch`. Now, both `master` & `new-branch` have the same latest code **locally** & **remotely**.

**My question is:**

How can I **revert** the **change** back on master branch both locally and remotely. **But keep all the changes only on** `new-branch` ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the master branch and do a `git revert HEAD` and `git push origin master`.
This will create a new commit that reverses the commit you want to undo.

You could also do a `git reset --hard HEAD^` (on the master branch) and a `git push -f origin master` (`-f` to force the push), but if anyone pulled the latest changes that you pushed it would cause problems for them.

The changes on the `new-branch` shouldn't be affected by these operations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have pushed it, the ideal way would be to `git revert` the commit in master and push master:

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD
git push origin master
```

The above will create a new commit which is the revert ( undoes the changes) of the previous

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you are already on your new branch.

```
git push . +master^:master
git push origin +master
```

This will allow you to not bother even checking out master in order to roll it back both locally and remotely.

Be careful in case someone is already working off of master. They will have to rebase their changes on top of the other commit if they want to push their changes.